# "Connot implicitily convert type 'System.Generic.Collection.IEnumerable<int> to <int>

Tags: c#, linq, collections, ienumerable, key-value

I am building a program that will take two user-selected cards from a standard deck of cards. The deck is made of KeyValuePair<int, string>s where it is set out as number then suit. After the user selects two cards, I need the program to add the integer parts of the cards together. I do not know how to get the Key parts of a KeyValuePair.

I know my code below obviously won't work, but I've included the image to show what I'm trying to do. My program should take the key value from the KeyValuePairs at the 'chosen card index, instead, it provides the error in the title of this post.

[Picture of my Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK4MK.png)

I have tried to convert the whole of the line to a string using Convert.ToInt32, but it also does not work. I have looked everywhere for a precise answer to this problem but with no luck.

Here's all the rest of the relevant code:

```
    public static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Player1Hand = new 
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(10); // creating the player's hand

    public static int chosencard;
    public static int player1total;
    public static string input;

    input = Console.ReadLine();
    chosencard2 = Int32.Parse(input);

    player1total = Hand.Player1Hand[chosencard];
    Console.WriteLine("Player 1's total is " + player1total);
```

Thanks, everyone for the help in advance.

Comment: Without any code best we can do is guess, and we dont do that here.
So please provide some code so we can see whats wrong. Linking a picture isnt enough.

Comment: Why using a `List<KeyValuePair>` when you could use a Dictionary?. If you did `Dictionary<int, string> Player1Hand`  you could just `Player1Hand.Keys`

Comment: Sorry, new here, I've added all the relevant code to the post. Cheers for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Player1Hand` is a List of `KeyValue<int, string>`. So what you are currently doing is accessing that pair, while you should access the key of that pair at the given index.

I think, with the information you gave me, this should do the trick:

```
player1Total += Hand.Player1Hand[chosencard].Key
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your posted picture you have a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` and access an element withing that list. As return type you get a `KeyValuePair<int, string>` which of course cannot be casted to `int`. Depending on what you want to achieve you might access either the [`Key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.key?view=net-5.0) or the [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.value?view=net-5.0) of your `KeyValuePair`. According to the types I would guess the `Key`.